# In Go, when using multiple return statements, how do you invoke each specific one?

Tags: sorting, types, interface, go, return-value

I am attempting to have two variations of the sort method: one form which sorts the elements by name, and another that sorts the elements by salary. sort.Sort(people(data)) works when my less method compares whatever.salary. It also works if I change it to whatever.name. I would like to be able to specifically call both of these options in the less method as shown in the below code. My logic is using sort.Sort(people(data.name)) for name, and sort.Sort(people(data.salary)) for salary. These are not working. Can this even be done?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Comparable interface {
    Len()
    Less(i, j int) bool
    Swap(i, j int)
}

type person struct {
    name   string
    salary float64
}

func (a person) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s: %g \n", a.name, a.salary)
}

type people []*person

func (a people) Len() int {
    return len(a)
}
func (a people) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return a[i].salary < a[j].salary
    return a[i].name < a[j].name
}
func (a people) Swap(i, j int) {
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}

func main() {

    var data = make(people, 10)

    var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j person

    a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name, e.name, f.name,
        g.name, h.name, i.name, j.name = "Sheila Broflovski", "Ben Affleck",
        "Mr. Hankey", "Stan Marsh", "Kyle Broflovski", "Eric Cartman",
        "Kenny McCormick", "Mr. Garrison", "Matt Stone", "Trey Parker"

    a.salary, b.salary, c.salary, d.salary, e.salary, f.salary,
        g.salary, h.salary, i.salary, j.salary = 82000, 74000, 0, 400,
        2500, 1000, 4, 34000, 234000, 234000
    a.salary = 82000

    data[0] = &a
    data[1] = &b
    data[2] = &c
    data[3] = &d
    data[4] = &e
    data[5] = &f
    data[6] = &g
    data[7] = &h
    data[8] = &i
    data[9] = &j

    fmt.Println("\n\n\n")
    fmt.Print(data)
    sort.Sort(people(data))        //This works even with the two return statements
    sort.Sort(people(data.name))   //This does not work. Exist, a version that does?
    sort.Sort(people(data.salary)) //This does not work. Exist, a version that does?
    fmt.Println("\n\n\n")
    fmt.Print(data)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to introduce the methods for sorting is to use a new type that describes the sorting condition. That's `byName` and `bySalary` here. Then you can sort using `sort.Sort(byName(data))`.

Here's some demonstration code. Go also has really great good for constructing data-structures (used prolifically, for example, in table-driven tests), which also can help construct your people data here.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sort"

type person struct {
    Name   string
    Salary float64
}

type people []*person

type byName people
type bySalary people

func (p byName) Len() int           { return len(p) }
func (p byName) Less(i, j int) bool { return p[i].Name < p[j].Name }
func (p byName) Swap(i, j int)      { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }

func (p bySalary) Len() int           { return len(p) }
func (p bySalary) Less(i, j int) bool { return p[i].Salary < p[j].Salary }
func (p bySalary) Swap(i, j int)      { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }

func main() {
    p := people{
        {"Sheila Broflovski", 82000},
        {"Ben Affleck", 74000},
        {"Mr. Hankey", 0},
        {"Stan Marsh", 400},
        {"Kyle Broflovski", 2500},
        {"Eric Cartman", 1000},
        {"Kenny McCormick", 4},
        {"Mr. Garrison", 34000},
        {"Matt Stone", 234000},
        {"Trey Parker", 234000},
    }
    fmt.Println("by name")
    sort.Sort(byName(p))
    for _, x := range p {
        fmt.Println(*x)
    }
    fmt.Println("by salary")
    sort.Sort(bySalary(p))
    for _, x := range p {
        fmt.Println(*x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement a second sort ordering with the standard library `sort` package, you will need to define a helper type that implements `sort.Interface`.  To handle the salary case in your example, you could do something like the following:

```
type bySalary struct {
    people
}

func (s bySalary) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s.people[i].salary < s.people[j].salary
}
```

Here, the `Len` and `Swap` methods required by `sort.Interface` come from the embedded `people` slice, while I've provided a replacement comparison operation.  To sort a `people` array, you can now call:

```
sort.Sort(bySalary{data})
```

Using this pattern, it is easy to implement as many additional sort keys as you need with very little duplicate code.

You can play with this example here: http://play.golang.org/p/kq3SuXMylT